# Opening Local HTML File: Chrome treats space as new tab?

Tags: google-chrome

When opening a local HTML file to see how it is rendering, Chrome is opening new tabs for every space in my file path, as shown:

[New tab for every space in file path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMKKz.png)

[Correct File Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15hEv.png)

This seems to be a recent issue, and the pages are opening correctly in Microsoft Edge, replacing the spaces with %20 encoding and loading. Does anybody know a setting in Chrome that can fix encoding issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem. Turns out this is due to an update that was installed on Chrome recently that requires an application relaunch to be fully functional. Closing all your chrome windows and reopening should fix the issue.